# Will android application get message about system locale changes?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

In JNI method I use call to Java objects  to get locale settings.

My JNI call is similar to Locale.getDefault() that I used to get it.

Will application be notified about system locale changes?

**So, typical usecase:**

1. Run my application.
2. In native code get locale from Locale.getDefault();
3. Change current system locale by settings menu on device.
4. In native code get locale from Locale.getDefault();

**Will I get actual information about current locale in step 4?**

Comment: No. Have no device right now. ((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Will I get actual information about current locale in step 4?**

Yes, I will.

But there is one issue:

If main activity blocked by native call , locale information will not change  till the main activity not recive ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED.

Answer (score 1):

An Intent is broadcast for this the `ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED` should let you know when a change in the preferences has happened. However if you're calling it after its changed without having been notified, you'll still get the new locale information.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED

Comment: I am using it only from native library. So I cannot fetch ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED event.